# How to store user state on client side?

Tags: reactjs, authentication, state, react-context

I have a MERN app with the frontend and backend deployed separately. I'm using passport to authenticate requests to my server using session cookies which works just fine.

I want to display some of the user's information on my frontend without having to send multiple requests to the server. I initially saved the user object using React's useContext() api, but noticed that this state isn't persisted on refresh. My workaround is writing the object to localStorage but that poses a security concern (user email and name are sensitive).

What is the correct way to store the user on the client?

Comment: You're right about the security concern of storing PII in localStorage. Nonetheless, the correct way would be doing a fetch for user data during the very initial `componentDidMount` life cycle. There are not really many options for handling PII properly.